# In Orchard CMS, is it possible to register IEventHandler implementations in modules to be called later than those that reside in Orchard.Framework?

Tags: c#, orchardcms, autofac

I am writing a module for Orchard CMS that contains an event handler class that implements the `IOrchardShellEvents` interface.

When a stock implementation of Orchard is set up using the Core recipe, and I enable my module, there are just three active implementations of `IOrchardShellEvents`. By default they are called in this order:

1. My custom event handler (in my custom module)
2. `AliasHolderUpdater` (from the `Orchard.Alias` module)
3. `AutomaticDataMigrations` (from `Orchard.Framework`).

I would like to set these up so that when the applicable event is fired, my class is called later than `AutomaticDataMigrations`.  I've tried playing with both the **Dependencies** and **Priority** fields in the `Modules.txt` of my module, but I cannot get my class to run later than `AutomaticDataMigrations`.

Things I have tried:

- I have tried adding **Dependencies: Orchard.Framework** to my module's `Module.txt`. This seems to do nothing. However, when I add **Dependencies: Orchard.Alias** to `Module.txt`, my class is indeed called later than `AliasHolderUpdater`. It just does not work for `AutomaticDataMigrations`, which is part of `Orchard.Framework`.
- I have tried adding **Priority: 1** to my module's `Module.txt`. This does indeed cause my class to get called later than other `IOrchardShellEvents` implementations that exist in modules, such as `AliasHolderUpdater`. However, even then it still calls `AutomaticDataMigrations` last.

Looking at the `ExtensionManager.AvailableFeatures` method, it can be seen that all features are loaded in order of dependency and priority. This means that the actual `IDependency` objects from each module are registered with AutoFac in this order.

(Details can be seen in `DependencyOrdering.OrderByDependenciesAndPriorities`, `CompositionStrategy.Compose`, and `ShellContainerFactory.CreateContainer` methods)

I do not see a way to control the order of registration of classes that reside in modules relative to those that reside in `Orchard.Framework`, which is not an "Orchard Module" and does not follow the normal rules of module loading.

Because the purpose of `AutomaticDataMigrations` is to ensure that the latest database migrations have been run, I would like for my class to be called later than it, so that when my event handler runs I can be sure it can make use of the database tables set up by the migrations.

How can I register my class to run later than `AutomaticDataMigrations`? Or, will this require modification of Orchard itself?

Comment: First of all, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have custom startup tasks that I want to run for my module. I want to ensure they run before any other code in my module runs. So I thought I want to write the code in a custom implementation of `IOrchardShellEvents.Activated`. But I want my code to run after `AutomaticDataMigrations`, in case there are DB changes, so that the DB migrations have already run.

Comment: What custom startup task?

Comment: That's part of what I want to do with my module and I can't tell you exactly.  I don't think my question is unreasonable.  I think there are many legitimate cases where I would want an event handler to run later than `AutomaticDataMigrations`.  For example, probably `AliasHolderUpdater.Activated` should run later than it as well, since it uses tables that may not exist until data migrations have already run.

Comment: I'm not saying it's unreasonable, I'm merely asking in order to see if there is an alternative to a very complicated implementation. If you can't tell me, then I'm sorry, but I can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to this problem and I believe it's actually a bug in Orchard.

`Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.CompositionStrategy` contains the following code:

```
    var enabledFeatures = _extensionManager.EnabledFeatures(descriptor);
    var features = _extensionManager.LoadFeatures(enabledFeatures);

    if (descriptor.Features.Any(feature => feature.Name == "Orchard.Framework"))
        features = features.Concat(BuiltinFeatures());
```

Feature descriptors are returned in "dependency" order from `EnabledFeatures()` -- items earlier in the list should not depend on items later in the list. This order is used when eventually building the dependency container.

Because `Orchard.Framework` should not depend on anything, and everything can depend on `Orchard.Framework`, this should come first ... and the code should look like this (only the last line here has been modified):

```
    var enabledFeatures = _extensionManager.EnabledFeatures(descriptor);
    var features = _extensionManager.LoadFeatures(enabledFeatures);

    if (descriptor.Features.Any(feature => feature.Name == "Orchard.Framework"))
        features = BuiltinFeatures().Concat(features);
```

This way, when dependencies are injected as part of a list (such as event handlers), built-in features should come first, since they have no dependencies.

This resolves my issue because I can rely on `Orchard.Framework`-provided `IOrcharShellEvents` implementations to be called before any provided by custom modules.

I have filed the above as a suggested fix in the Orchard issue tracker: http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20286